# Defining Relationship ( Many to Many) for 3 Models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord, relationship

I have three models in Rails as : Curriculum, Grade and Topics.

The relationship scenario is like :

> Curriculum 'C1' in grade 'G1' has_many Topics ( t1,t2,t3)
>
> Curriculum 'C2' in grade 'G2' has_many Topics (t1,t2,t4,t5) [ A
>   Topic can be in many different curriculums but might be taught in different
>   grades ]

Grade G1 can itself be a part of multiple Curriculums like C1, C2

I need to store information such that for a Topic t1, I can say:

> It is taught in C1 in grade G1
>
> It is taught in C2 in grade G2

How can I set this up in Rails?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to model what you're after, I believe?

```
class Curriculum < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :grades
end

class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :curriculum
  has_and_belongs_to_many :topics
class

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :grades
end
```

Comment: Perhaps this will make sense.

    CurriculumA
      Grade1
       Topic1
       Topic2
    CurriculumB
      Grade2
       Topic1
       Topic3